# git clone ssh syntax difference?

Tags: ssh, git, docker, gitlab, protocols

#### Setup

There is a host (*H1*) running gitlab-ce git server within a docker container (*C1*). The host's OpenSSH server runs on port 22 and provides a host key *keyH*. The gitlab container provides its own SSH service that is published to host like `10022:22` and provides an own host key *keyC*.

#### Problem

On a separate client system, when calling `git clone git@H1:10022/<group>/<project>` I expect to get connection to the SSH server within container *C1*. Indeed, I only get connection to host *H1* and I get *keyH* presented (it seems port 22 of the host is used for cloning). Of cause, that leads to a failed clone.

#### But

Generally (from the same client) pulling and pushing form this dockerized git server works when defining a remote like:

```
git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@H1:10022/group/project.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@H1:10022/group/project.git (push)
```

So it seems, there is a difference in protocol between `ssh://git@H1...` and `git@H1...`. But I think git is communicating via HTTP(S) or SSH, only? What is the difference/problem here?

#### Platform

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 (todays upstream patch level)
- git client 1.9.1
- gitlab 7.13-stable official Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **git-clone**(1):

```
GIT URLS
...
       The following syntaxes may be used with them:

       o   ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
...
       An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol:

       o   [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/
```

The scp-like syntax doesn't have any way to specify an alternate port. scp supports port selection with the `-P` option, but that option wasn't carried over into the git tools.

The `user@host:path` syntax of scp is an imitation of rcp, and rcp predates the web, so it doesn't follow URL conventions. It only coincidentally looks kind of like a schemeless URL.

`git@H1:10022/group/project.git` specifies the user `git` on the host `H1`, and a relative path `10022/group/project.git` from that user's home directory.

To access an ssh server on port 10022 you're going to have to use the `ssh://` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, somehow, I just have read over this part of the man page...